# Revolution Slider edit screen not loading in Wordpress multisite

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

We have a website that has Revolution Slider installed.

About a month ago, we configured the site into a directory based multisite with both main site and subsite themes being different, but both using the same Revolution Slider plugin.

The problem now is that on the main site, the Revolution Slider edit screen that loads via Wordpress Dashboard is not loading if at all. Opening the Chrome Console Network tab shows that there is a long time trying to load "admin-ajax.php". It times out after 30 seconds.

This is making it extremely hard for our client to edit the slideshow.

Is this an issue with Revolution Slider itself (needs a reinstallation) or the database (corrupted data), and if so, how do we go about rectifying the issue.

Thank you.